# What does -P INPUT ACCEPT mean with regards to iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables

I'm fairly new to iptables, and am trying to figure out if I've configured my ruleset appropriately.  With regards to the **-P INPUT ACCEPT** part of my question, I am trying to determine if this is valid in the context of the rules I want to apply.  Please see below for further details.

I have used **iptables-restore** with a file containing the following rules.  Essentially, I am attempting to allow loopback traffic, established/related connections, SSH, and HTTP.  All other traffic should be rejected.

```
*filter
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]

# Input chain rules
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
# Reject all other inbound traffic
-A INPUT -j REJECT   

# Output chain rules
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Forward chain rules
-A FORWARD -j REJECT                                    

# fail2ban-ssh chain rules
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 146.0.77.33/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 62.75.236.76/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN

COMMIT
```

If I run **iptables -S**, I receive the following output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 146.0.77.33/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 62.75.236.76/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

I've done a bit of reading on iptables, and my understanding is that the first few lines (e.g., "**-P INPUT ACCEPT**") essentially mean that the default action if none of the other rules apply is to accept the traffic (in this case, for input, forward and output).

If this is the case, should I explicitly put the following lines in my rules file and restore iptables again?

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
```

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who reads this full question!  It's a bit long, but I thought it would be necessary to include all of the above details to adequately explain my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question that you actually asked, the policies should appear in a normal `iptables-save` file, but not as the argument to `-P` rules.

Instead, they should appear at the beginning, along with your declaration of any custom chains, with their policies, like so:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
```

The hyphen by your custom chain is a missing policy argument, because user-defined chains don't have policies.

Note that, with your firewall as written, if you change all the policies to `DROP`, your server will have difficulty doing DNS lookups, and many things will fail unpredictably.

Comment: Thanks!  Ideally I would still like to lock it down as much as possible - also, I'm okay with leaving output mostly open as I would imagine input/forward traffic is the main concern.

Comment: In this example, what does [0:0] signify?

Comment: @RogerMungo packet and byte counts to be set at initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, other than anything fail2ban blocks, your current rules mean you don't have firewall.
Consider how your firewall would respond in the following scenario:

You are running MySQL or some other database that is listening on a TCP connection for local connections - but you don't want remote connections.
Then a malicious remote machine tries to access a mysql server on port `3306`.
Assuming fail2ban hasn't blocked them, the question is
will any of your existing rules help you? what about:

- `-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`  - NOPE
- `-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` - NOPE
- `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` - NOPE

etc... nothing matches and DROPs the connection so your INPUT policy applies and the connection is accepted.
Then consider the same scenario **for any and every other service running on you machine** - if fail2ban hasn't blocked, your server will let them in.
So yes, I suggest you add to your `iptables-restore` rules

```
-P INPUT DROP
# Any unmatched packets  on FORWARD chain will be dropped
-P FORWARD DROP
```

Note: whilst iptables rules typically won't persist beyond a reboot,  a policy will.
In this case, the rule above will lock a SSH session out if there is no
corresponding ACCEPT rule which got loaded after on a server reboot - i.e. this policy would lock you out.
Personally I would still use the drop policy, but some people like to keep the `-P INPUT ACCEPT` and instead use

```
-A INPUT DROP
```

as a rule right at the bottom of your INPUT chain as a "quasi" policy.  You have to be careful with this and keep re-reading your rules when you modify your file wall, but if you didn't setup iptables to restore its rules on reboot this arrangement would mean you could get back into your machine.

Comment: Thanks!  Please note in the rules I listed I have -A INPUT -p REJECT, shouldn't that cover all of the exceptions I've listed?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to add something to my last comment.  I don't mean to use iptables as a replacement for a firewall, and understand that having port 80 for HTTP connections open still leaves me susceptible to attacks.  That being said, I still want to use something simple like iptables to at least drop/reject all traffic other than what I expect the server to be used for.

Comment: Last comment, I promise :) I have a typo in my first comment, I meant to say -j REJECT

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I just dumped your rules (the `INPUT` chain) into [fffuu](http://iptables.isabelle.systems/) to extract a simplified version. It only shows who may establish connections:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0    
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    dports: 22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    dports: 80
DROP       tcp  --  146.0.77.33/32       0.0.0.0/0    dports: 22
DROP       tcp  --  62.75.236.76/32      0.0.0.0/0    dports: 22
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0    
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

You can see that your fail2ban approach is actually broken: The second rule accepts all ssh connections; rules number 4 and 5 (the DROP rules) are shadowed (they can never be reached).

I assume your default policy is `ACCEPT`, which you can see as the last rule in the simplified listing. As you might also see, the default policy for `INPUT` doesn't matter here because the second last rule already drops all packets which did not match a rule before. This is because of your `-A INPUT -j REJECT` rule.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I'm actually okay with that, those rules were there by default when I installed fail2ban and I've since taken them out. -edit: also changed the default policy to drop, all is working well!

Comment: As mentioned before: With a default policy of `DROP`, make sure you won't lock yourself out of the server if you ever run `iptables -F`.

Comment: Good call! I can access the server locally in that scenario though, so it should be all good.